# adding a symbolic trait to a selected range

Tags: objective-c, xcode

what i need to do is adding a symbolic trait to a selected range so if it is italic and i pressed bold button then it should be italic and bold

```
   - (IBAction)boldedSelectedText:(UIButton*)sender {
   UIFontDescriptor* bodyFontDescriptor=[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
  UIFontDescriptor* boldFontdescriptor=[bodyFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
  self.body.font=[UIFont  fontWithDescriptor:boldFontdescriptor size:0.0];
}
- (IBAction)italicSelectedText:(UIButton *)sender {
  UIFontDescriptor* bodyFontDescriptor=[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor* italicFontdescriptor=[bodyFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
self.body.font=[UIFont  fontWithDescriptor:italicFontdescriptor size:0.0];
}
```

the problem is when i select a text and make it bold then italic , it become italic only and vice it can not be bold and italic at the same time i don't know what should i do to add anew trait to previous traits?

Answer (score 1):

The Font Symbolic Trait is a bitmask (NS_OPTIONS). You need to set the flag to either one or both based on your selected options.
Something like :

```
    UIFontDescriptor* italicBoldFontdescriptor = [bodyFontDescriptor 
        fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute:
            @{ UIFontSymbolicTrait: @(UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) } 
        }];
```

The `fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes` will, as the per the doc,

> returns a new font descriptor that is the same as the receiver but with the specified attributes taking precedence over the existing one

This will allow you to keep other settings.